# Class has no parameterless constructor exception in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, model-view-controller

I'm trying to do the Entity Framework Code First Approach. I made my models then the DbContext and added it to the controller. I followed an online tutorial as I've never used C# before.

However the tables don't create until I add a call to the db in the controller.

```
public ActionResult Index()
     {
        db.posts.ToList();

        return View();
     }
```

The call however throws.

InvalidOperationException: The class 'SocialMediaMining.Models.SocialMedia.Facebook.posts' has no parameterless constructor.

posts class:

```
public class posts
    {
        public dynamic jsonObj { get; set; }
        public posts(dynamic json)
    {
        jsonObj = json;

        if (jsonObj != null)
        {

            id = jsonObj.id;
            name = jsonObj.name;
            if(jsonObj.feed !=null)
            {
                feed = new feed(jsonObj.feed);

            }
        }
    }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public virtual feed feed { get; set; }

    public int postsId { get; set; }
}
```

The controller:

```
public class FacebookController : Controller
{
      //The dbcontext call
      FacebookEntities db = new FacebookEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // the error
        db.posts.ToList();

        return View();
    }
// more code here
}
```

//DbContext

```
public class FacebookEntities : DbContext
    {
     public FacebookEntities() :  base("SocialMediaDb")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<posts> posts { get; set; }

  //more code here
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: In C# by default parameter less constructor available .. but if you add any parameter  constructor  then framework will remove default parameter less constructor .. in you case You have added a parameter constructor so parameter less constructor won't be available and from somewhere parameter less constructor getting referred .. so try to add parameter less constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception message is pretty straightforward - you need to specify a parameterless constructor for `posts` class, which should look like this:

```
public class posts
{    
    // add this constructor
    public posts()
    {
    }

    public dynamic jsonObj { get; set; }

    public posts(dynamic json)
    {
        jsonObj = json;

        if (jsonObj != null)
        {

            id = jsonObj.id;
            name = jsonObj.name;
            if(jsonObj.feed !=null)
            {
                feed = new feed(jsonObj.feed);

            }
        }
    }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public virtual feed feed { get; set; }

    public int postsId { get; set; }
}
```

Note that any entity class which want to be included in `DbSet<T>` type parameter must have parameterless constructor to enable binding with EF. Also it is recommended to use PascalCase for entity class names and property names, e.g. `Posts`.

Comment: Oh man, that was so simple ... the tutorials didn't have that and it ran for some reason. Anyways, its working now thank you